# jQuery - Replace all anchor tags with href="#" with Javascript:Void(0)

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am trying to replace all anchor tags with href="#" and replace the value to Javascript:Void(0) instead of # across the application but the same is getting applied to all anchor tags (even the ones with links). Below is the code I am using.

```
$('a').attr('href', '#').each(function () {
  $(this).attr('href', 'JavaScript:Void(0)');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS selectors to most effectively complete this.

```js
$("a[href=#]").attr("href","javascript:void(0)")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#'>testing link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this:

```
$('a[href=#]').each(function () {
  $(this).attr('href', 'JavaScript:Void(0)');
});
```

See it running: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/sow37f0a

The third link `href` remains untouched because it is not `"#"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").find("a").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("href")=="#"){
            $(this).attr("href","javascript:void(0)")
        }
    })
})
```